# SQL: How to count rows from the numeric assignment values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I started learning SQL since yesterday, I hope you guys can help me. Also, I'm kind of bad in writing and explaining. Hope you get what I'm trying to say.

I have a field "MANUAL_ENTRY". which accepts values 0, 1 , 3

```
CASE MANUAL_ENTRY WHEN 0 then 'Agent' 
                  when 1 then 'Manual' 
                  when 2 then 'WSAPI' 
                  when 3 then REMOTE_HOST_PROTOCOL.SOURCE 
                  else 'Unknown' END
```

I am able to get the count for `COUNT(WHEN 0 then 'Agent' end)`

But, can't get to count the values for 'Unknown'.

I kind of tried this `COUNT(CASE MANUAL_ENTRY When '' then 'Unknown' end)` but, asking myself how can I assume a NULL value is being written to it.

how can I COUNT records for 'Unknown'?

-Praveen

Comment: Does NULL values must be counted as Unknown too? If true then `SUM(CASE WHEN MANUAL_ENTRY IN (0,1,2,3) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response and the help @Akina. that worked like a charm. Heard StackOverflow is a great community did not expect faster response.

Comment: or `SELECT count(manual_entry) - count(*)`   Because `count(manual_entry)` count the values which are no null, and `count(*)` counts all values.

Comment: @Luuk If only NULLs must be counted then `SUM(manual_entry IS NULL)` is the most obvious variant.

Comment: Or, for counting all value not equal to 0,1,2 or 3, one could do `sum(case i when 0 then 0 when 1 then 0 when 2 then 0 when 3 then 0 else 1 end)`